# Error in Time to update ZF2 + doctrine

Tags: php, zend-framework2, doctrine

People I'm having problem in time to make the edit with the doctrine.

the following error occurs: **Fatal error: Call to a member function persist() on a non-object in**

below is my code:

```
public function editAction()
{

    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

    $user_update = $this->getEntityManager()->find('CodeDemo\Entity\User', $id);

    $user_update->setName('User example');
    $user_update->setEmail('user@example.com');
    $user_update->setDate(new \DateTime('02/02/02'));

    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($user_update);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

}
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Was that the entity manager was null , so giving fatal error!